# Accessing NSWindow in Mac Catalyst

Tags: ios, swift, macos, mac-catalyst

I am aware that NSWindow is not officially available in Mac Catalyst but I have seen several posts and success stories accessing it via `NSClassFromString` and `valueForKeyPath`. However, I have never been able to get this to work, as it always returns nil.

```swift
guard let nsWindows = NSClassFromString("NSApplication")?.value(forKeyPath: "sharedApplication.windows") as? [AnyObject] else {
    return nil
}
```

Have also attempted in objective c with

```
NSArray *const nsWindows = [NSClassFromString(@"NSApplication") valueForKeyPath:@"sharedApplication.windows"];
```

But the same result - nil - every time.

Is there a trick to getting this to work, or has this way been shut down as a potential way to access it? It successfully can get the NSApplication instance. But the windows property is always nil.

Comment: You should be looking for the scene UIWindow

Comment: @LeoDabus I need NSWindow to change the size of the window programmatically

Comment: Seems correct https://gist.github.com/steipete/30c33740bf0ebc34a0da897cba52fefe

Comment: @nserror I think my answer in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58526250/is-it-possible-to-use-full-screen-in-mac-catalyst/58679398 might be useful for you.

Comment: `But the windows property is always nil.` >> This is because you accessing NSWindow to early. It might be not yet `main/key/etc`. Wrap the call into `DispatchQueue.main.async { }`.

Answer (score 5):

This can be done easily with the help of [Dynamic](https://github.com/mhdhejazi/Dynamic):

```swift
extension UIWindow {
    var nsWindow: NSObject? {
        var nsWindow = Dynamic.NSApplication.sharedApplication.delegate.hostWindowForUIWindow(self)
        if #available(macOS 11, *) {
            nsWindow = nsWindow.attachedWindow
        }
        return nsWindow.asObject
    }
}
```

Comment: Facing issue with Dynamic. is it Really working? @Hejazi

Comment: @ohmprakash I updated the code to support macOS 11.