# Using Launcher in .NET MAUI to open a PDF file for viewing

Tags: .net, maui, mac-catalyst

I have a .net maui app that I am trying to get running on MacOS (Catalyst).

When using the [example provided in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/appmodel/launcher?view=net-maui-7.0&tabs=macios#open-another-app-via-a-file)  a "share" dialog open up instead of the PDF file and the default viewer.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydSOT.png)

It does the same thing when using the exact code from the docs:

```cs
string popoverTitle = "Read text file";
string name = "File.txt";
string file = System.IO.Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, name);

System.IO.File.WriteAllText(file, "Hello World");

await Launcher.Default.OpenAsync(new OpenFileRequest(popoverTitle, new ReadOnlyFile(file)));
```

I associated pdf files with Chrome, and they display fine when launced from Finder.

Any help or work-arounds would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: _If more than one app is registered with the file type, an app selection popover is shown to the user._ So pdf file type may register with more than one App.

Comment: Thank you for your reply; however it is popping up a "share" extension selector, not an app selector. If I click on "Edit Extensions" for the document type, I can select things like AirDrop or Messages (for example), not "Previewer" or "Chrome", etc.

Comment: Found a known issue on Github : [Launcher Feature does not open file correctly on IOS.](https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/issues/2027)

Comment: Thank you. That's for Xamarin, and the suggestion in the thread is to move to MAUI - it's a shame the problem still exists there. I'll log a bug in the MAUI repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is standard Catalyst behaviour - Catalyst apps use iOS API, and that API opens the PDF via share.

You can look at the MAUI source to see what exactly the launcher code is doing:

The [iOS Launcher code](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/blob/main/src/Essentials/src/Launcher/Launcher.ios.tvos.cs) (used in MAUI / MacCatalyst) calls [UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrlAsync](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1648685-openurl):

```
Task<bool> PlatformOpenAsync(NSUrl nativeUrl) =>
    UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrlAsync(nativeUrl, new UIApplicationOpenUrlOptions());
```

The [MacOS Launcher code](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/blob/main/src/Essentials/src/Launcher/Launcher.macos.cs) (used in a .Net for MacOS app, but not in a MAUI / MacCatalyst app) calls [NSWorkspace.SharedWorkspace.OpenFile](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace):

```
Task<bool> PlatformOpenAsync(OpenFileRequest request) =>
    Task.FromResult(NSWorkspace.SharedWorkspace.OpenFile(request.File.FullPath));
```

The NSWorkspace version is not available to MacCatalyst apps, so you can't readily bypass the MAUI launcher code to call it.

To get the MacOS behaviour you'll need to launch from a MacOS context. With a bit of trickiness, you can bridge to a MacOS context from your MacCatalyst app and call the MacOS API from there. To do so, include a MacOS bundle in with your Maui Catalyst project and use it to call the MacOS API (Catalyst app -> MacOS bridge component -> MacOS API).

[Is it possible to use full screen in Mac Catalyst?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58679398/4068779) walks through the pieces and shows how to NSApplication from a MacCatalyst app. The concepts will be the same to call NSWorkspace from .Net Catalyst app.